# Geometric Sums in Banach Algebra

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $E$ be a [Banach Algebra with identity](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra), and $v\in E$, so that $||v|| < 1$. The geometric series $w = \sum_{k=0}^\infty v^k$  converges in the norm.

I can show that $||w|| \le \frac{1}{1-||v||}$, but does the equality hold? If it holds, how can I show this?  If it doesn't hold, are there counterexamples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\tfrac{e}{2})^k = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\tfrac{1}{2})^k\right)e = \frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}e = \tfrac{2}{3}e $$
because it's just a regular geometric series of real numbers times $e$, while $\frac{1}{1-\lVert -\frac{e}{2} \rVert} = 2$.

(Much belated) edit: corrected the summation.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\tfrac{e}{2})^k = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\tfrac{1}{2})^k\right)e$$ I don't quite understand how they are equal. Shouldn't $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\tfrac{1}{2})^k\right)e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\tfrac{e}{2^k})$$ Am I missing something?

Comment: $e$ is the identity, so $e^k = e$ for all $k$

Comment: oh I see that makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

You can.  You have the following if $\|x\| < 1$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|x^n\| \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \|x\|^n \le {1\over {1 - \|x\|}}.$$
This geometric sum is absolutely convergent and therefore convergent (Banach
algebras are complete).  It is not difficult to show that
$$(e - x)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n,$$
where $e$ denotes the identity in the Banach algebra.

Comment: Equality occurs on the positive real axis in the Banach algebra $\Bbb C$ inside of the open unit disk.